# R replace misspelled words

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
state=data.frame(ST=c('ANDAMAN & NICOBAR',              
'ANDHRA PRADESH',               
'APO',              
'AR',               
'ARUNACHAL PRADESH',                
'ASSAM',                
'BIHAR',                
'CHANDIGARH',               
'CHHATTISGARH',         
'DADRA AND NAGAR',
'DELHI',                
'GOA',              
'GUJARAT',              
'HARYANA',              
'HIMACHAL PRADESH',             
'JAMMU & KASHMIR',              
'JHARKHAND',                
'KARNATAKA',                
'KERALA',               
'LADAKH',
'LAKSHADWEEP',              
'MADHYA PRADESH',               
'MAHARASHTRA',              
'MANIPUR',              
'MEGHALAYA',                
'MIZORAM',              
'NAGALAND',             
'NEW DELHI',                
'NL',               
'ODISHA',
'ORISSA',               
'PB',               
'PONDICHERRY',              
'PUDUCHERRY',               
'PUNJAB',               
'PUNJAB/MOHALI/ZIRAKPUR',               
'RAJASTHAN',                
'RAJSHTHAN',                
'RAJSTHAN',             
'RJ',
'SIKKIM',               
'TAMIL NADU',               
'TELANGANA',                
'TRIPURA',              
'UTTAR PRADESH',                
'UTTARAKHAND',              
'WEST BENGAL'))
state
```

There are some misspellings and abbreviations I'm trying to correct. For example, Rajasthan has three different spellings and an abbreviation. I need each state to have only one representation. With respect to Rajasthan, I've tried:

```
state %>% 
  replace(ST , c('RAJSHTHAN','RJ','RAJSTHAN'), 'RAJASTHAN')
```

Throws an 'unused argument' error.
Tried it like this too:

```
state %>% 
  replace(ST , 'RAJSHTHAN'|'RJ'|'RAJSTHAN', 'RAJASTHAN')
```

Same error.
Tried this as well:

```
x=c("RAJSHTHAN","RJ","RAJSTHAN")
state$ST[state$ST == x]= replace(ST,x, 'RAJASTHAN')
state
```

No dice.
Also this:

```
for (ST in state) {if(ST = "RAJSHTHAN"|"RJ"|"RAJSTHAN"){ST = 'RAJASTHAN'}}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Ultimately this will be applied to a large dataset.
I pulled it from my dataset using:

```
state_name = distinct(df, `ship-state`)
colnames(state_name)[1] = 'ST'
state_name = state_name[order(state_name$ST), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use quote marks inside the pattern:

```
library(stringr)
state %>% 
  str_replace(ST, 'RAJSHTHAN|RJ|RAJSTHAN', 'RAJASTHAN')
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I get the message: `Error in str_replace(., ST, "RAJSHTHAN|RJ|RAJSTHAN", "RAJASTHAN") : 
  unused argument ("RAJASTHAN")` when running your code. I also loaded the data and library beforehand so not sure if its just an issue on my end.

Comment: There should not be the `.` in the function call.  Remove it, and input `ST` as data, as in the answer...

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann  Thanks for the info on quotes inside patterns. I would've never figured that one out.

Answer (score 0):

It is the piping throwing it off. The following code works:

```
state$ST = str_replace(ST, c('RAJSHTHAN|RJ|RAJSTHAN'), 'RAJASTHAN')
```

Comment: There's no need for the function `c` if you use a regex alternation pattern